# Generating function - zeros when $n\in \mathbb{N}_{odd}$

Tags: generating-functions

It is given that $a_n$ is generated by the following function:
$${1+6x} \over {(1+5x)(1-x)}$$

What is the generating function of:
$$\left\{ {\matrix{
   {{a_n},\mathbb{N}_{even}}  \cr 
   {0,\mathbb{N}_{odd}}  \cr 
 } } \right.$$

I'm guessing it's a technical issue, which i am lacking of.
I'll be glad for an explanation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}$.

Comment: it has something with $\sinh(x)$ maybe? I recall it generates somewhat similar series. I am not quite sure how to use your hint.

Comment: It is only vaguely related. In general, if you have $f(x)=a_0+a_1 x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\cdots$, then $a_0+a_2x^2+a_4x^4+\cdots$ is $(1/2)[f(x)+f(-x)]$. For plug in $-x$ for $x$ and add. The odd terms cancel. It is similar to the way we get the series for $\cosh(x)$ from the series for $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$. In your case, the answer would be $\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1+6x} {(1+5x)(1-x)}+ \frac{1-6x}{(1-5x)(1+x)}\right]$, which we can simplify further if we wish.

Comment: In your case, the desired generating function simplifies to (I think) $\frac{1-29x^2)}{(x^2-1)(25x^2-1)}$. You could also use partial fractions to simplify the original generating function before doing the $(1/2)(f(x)+f(-x))$ bit.

Comment: You are welcome. To eliminate the even terms, we would have used $(1/2)(f(x)-f(-x))$. There are similar tricks using complex numbers to "eliminate" other terms of the generating function.